# How to validate user input while running a while with those values

Tags: python, validation, input, while-loop, try-except

I'm writing a password generator that asks the user to enter a password LENGHT and generates it that long (it works)

**Problem**: I do validate user input (while/try/except), it gets the Value Error right, it gets the minimum length right BUT it does not take the maximum value and generates always the SAME password with the length PLUS the new length.

Maybe some examples will help

```
from random import randint

lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upperCase = lowerCase.upper()
numbers = "1234567890"
special = "!#$%&/()=?¡@[]_<>,."

password_creation = lowerCase + upperCase + numbers + special

password = ""
lenght = 0
while True
    try:
        password_lenght = int(input("How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: "))
        if password_lenght < 8 or password_lenght > 1024:
            print("Minimun 8 characters - maximum 1024, try again")
    except ValueError:
        print ("Please enter a valid NUMBER...")
        continue
    else:
        while lenght < password_lenght:



        password = password + password_creation[randint(0, len(password_creation) -1)]
        lenght +=1
              
    
        print("Generated password: ", password)
```

if I run this code it kind of works:

```
>>> %Run z_strong_password_gen.py
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: asdsads
Please enter a valid NUMBER...
```

ok, it detects if I enter non-numerical values,

now let's try a number below 8 (the minimum.

```
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: 1
Minimun 8 characters - maximum 1024, try again
Generated password:  $
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: 3
Minimun 8 characters - maximum 1024, try again
Generated password:  $?$)
```

ok, it goes with the message "Minimun 8 characters - maximum 1024, try again" BUT it calculates the password

now let's try with the maximum

```
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: 1030
Minimun 8 characters - maximum 1024, try again
Generated password:  $?$NDcB&vMDY&IX@¡x#hLxP8u!oa_F6PGg&DQV8WBOwkqJW@VJ8nmFA$wrF]7soN<C(J[x#[HRm,xL(7(OiCcdV43#XUfa9o7LYwBq55[n24geBl=@U<&!$fH]01&>]bG3/l&[>u2mA4N9IiNUUTj=tWJ)g4wz>A67qNV7O]aKZVfvc3F?B/TCsCjzYe3pOQ%f1nrvFO7prBr[C_Eqs8W?7GU/vor/>xJtV.FLKUL94)KZ(JCc1#gFv,=wJ5rvBR2[5)hhv[tAi)&8AXB1n)FPyUi6WZeqzWnj@R0t.WYja%r2pD_3¡hoW7nRncdf,ExV5._)W(/P3yOyvp#jZNpQIt6Y1cbfoq[mweSp#f)¡ADNz_Duibe<U9pJD4]4x,/G51fORryfVaekX=PIes?T>KTvfy>sQMgNjZ]4M,=5vD!G%,/gYZn(J_pxJlKzjUE65VJn)ZRVpI!&dHDtK(vh=IN=p4i7#E¡4[r!.$]J@>4&HQqSq?DXyvis<Gs)@$=5I/SRGV2&¡]DU0P$=CF,hoj7@]KhPLWsWrFgC@nEU8i3jC3yZKt)_r=m?@KH<sA$D#,f_2%rV$gwzMZoyxh=b[kBD5N%k<1SEpc<f93.)9eh74D6oi)XkylTNA3O%Vq)eUpF9VA$H5)NYUBHihMW.$O#ytgb!24?WLzi>piF0T(!6V#l1141v@i%]_BxCV2uPEPdajOdxqkJs#Fq,zAa#T.%DE%D%,I<y4zY5lgBcua!,LBu1jHf%4waKujW.Y&WMpnf<qa%#sCZlGm17iNu9fRLXXAdO[1s@g4?ZhTL60Blg?PtZNJw<AB>$poCK¡cJ7ON$kXAEZ/c¡X/H]FCHhjCVUm#na¡p_o>]7Bp//rr3YJFj<OpCL2kg,,XEsC0¡<i/$HP#Bc!X#nMlRVMW8NdV7x7ru_(2OW6/Q1P¡c_ZmJz<Z<7zELz¡6yp00$ZD&sErhSz81mVU$oO(rtqAYs=p3h%lbTr$EWiJxvq)X<z909k18rN07ZRfq@C7hWRyTH1!?&PR3%@?
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024:
```

It raises the message that the number is bigger than 1024 BUT it calculates the password again

And if I do calculate a password, let's say, 10 characters..it does ok, if I want to calculate another one of...20, it takes the first 10 from the previous calculation and just add 10 more to fill the 20 (maybe I have to clear or delelte the varaiable)

check the example

```
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: 10
Generated password:  **fOweHv%Wm,**
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: 20
Generated password:  **fOweHv%Wm,**p6AEoh8L)l
How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track. You simply forgot to reset the password, when we restart the while loop. And also you didn't continue after printing the error for the min and max length. But when that's fixed, it works:

```py
from random import randint

lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upperCase = lowerCase.upper()
numbers = "1234567890"
special = "!#$%&/()=?¡@[]_<>,."

password_creation = lowerCase + upperCase + numbers + special

while True:
    # pulled password and length in here to reset on each loop
    password = ""
    length = 0
    try:
        password_length = int(input("How many characters do you wish the password? Minimum 8 maximum 1024: "))
        if password_length < 8 or password_length > 1024:
            print("Minimun 8 characters - maximum 1024, try again")
            # add continue, to not try to create password, if validation fails
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid NUMBER...")
        continue
    else:
        while length < password_length:
            password = password + password_creation[randint(0, len(password_creation) - 1)]
            length += 1
        print("Generated password: ", password)
```

I also renamed `lenght` and `password_lenght` to `length` and `password_length`, so be mindful of that, if you use them elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it
It validates user input to catch the error if enters a non-digit character
it checks if the value entered is in range
it calculates the password
it exits once done

here the code, it took me all day but...I was able to

```
from random import randint

lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upperCase = lowerCase.upper()
numbers = "1234567890"
special = "!#$%&/()=?¡@[]_<>,."

mega_pass = lowerCase+ upperCase + numbers + special

lenght = 0
password_lenght = 0
password = ""


while True:
    try:
        password_lenght = int(input("How many characters long do you want the password? (min 8 - max 100; \n"))

except ValueError:
    print("\nNumbers please...")

if  password_lenght not in range (8, 101):
    print("\nEnter a digit between 8 and 100...")


    

else:
    while lenght < password_lenght:
        password = password + mega_pass[randint(0, len(mega_pass) -1)]
        lenght +=1
    
    print("\nYou choose" , password_lenght , "characters long\n")
    print("Here is your PASSWORD:\n ", password)
    break
```

here the output

> > > %Run z_strong_password_gen_v2.py
> > > How many characters long do you want the password? (min 8 - max 100;
> > > ghfhf hf677

Numbers please...

Enter a digit between 8 and 100...
How many characters long do you want the password? (min 8 - max 100;
0

Enter a digit between 8 and 100...
How many characters long do you want the password? (min 8 - max 100;
4444+

Numbers please...

Enter a digit between 8 and 100...
How many characters long do you want the password? (min 8 - max 100;
77

You choose 77 characters long

Here your PASSWORD:
[M6HlFc>4EBktF(zFQQX)Tp((&ckfCVze7#!0LQOWGQ_5aT2X]fiam%0dVU42tidOJe0h]e<$RTJh